# Lakeformation and Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lake-formation

After reading the documentation I have a question related to Lakeformation and Redshift. Is it true that while using lakeformation the available data for the consumer accounts is only going to be through S3. If this is true then if I want to share information which is a Redshift/Postgres Database in a producer account then I  will have to dump to S3 before it can be shared with any consumer account.

**Is S3 the only possible way of sharing information between the producers and consumers when using Lakeformation**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, LakeFormation only works with Glue and S3, glue for metadata and S3 for data storage. LakeFormation really is just a little bit of extra permissioning on top of Glue, nothing more.

Maybe https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cross-account-data-sharing-for-amazon-redshift/ can be of help to you, there are other ways to share Redshift data, not using LakeFormation.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing of AWS RedShift native objects looks like is now possible to be shared using LakeFormation. It is still in preview mode. The below links will help understand the approach

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/amazon-redshift-data-sharing-centralized-access-control-lake-formation-preview/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/centrally-manage-access-and-permissions-for-amazon-redshift-data-sharing-with-aws-lake-formation/